# Saving a video in opencv library of python

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a program using open computer vision library to enhance the underwater images/videos , the program has worked completely however when I try to save the video, the video can't be played and it says that video format is not supported

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Images/tubb.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),fx=0.5,fy=0.5)
    cv2.imshow('original new',frame)
    frame1 = frame
    frame1[:,:,2] = cv2.equalizeHist(frame1[:,:,2])


    img_lab = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    img_lab[:,:,0] = np.clip(img_lab[:,:,0] * 1.5, 0, 225)

    img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img_lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    #img_bgr = cv2.addWeighted(img,3.5,img_bgr,-2,-0.5)

    cv2.imshow('output', img_bgr)
    cv2.imshow('original',frame)
    out.write(img_bgr)
    if cv2.waitKey(6)== 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You forgot to call `out.release()` and the end - the video file was not properly closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have written cap.release()

Comment: did you know that you call `resize()`? check the frame size. `.write()` requires exactly what you promised to `VideoWriter`

Comment: I have changed the size in the .write() function but the problem is still there

Comment: `assert out.isOpened()`